# Use Powershell to get data from Defender Advanced Hunting Queries

Tags: powershell

I have an advanced query on Defender to extract the number of vulnerabilities by it's severity type, which is this one:

```
DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities
| summarize count() by  VulnerabilitySeverityLevel
| order by VulnerabilitySeverityLevel
```

Basically this produces a very simple table with this data:

Critical - 1000
High - 1000
Medium - 1000
Low - 1000

Is there any way to get this query from Powershell, so then I can do some extra tasks after?

Thanks

Comment: Here are the CLI commands for Defenders. CLI az command can be run from powershell or the SDK,   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/security?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: This page may more useful, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint/advanced-hunting-query-powershell-command-line/m-p/3611154

Comment: @mzm This page references one other thing which is detecting powershell commands within Defender. What I want is to use Powershell to extract data from Defender.